# What is the purpose of the ACE entry SYSTEM in a Windows DACL?

Tags: windows, access-control, dacl

What is the purpose of the ACE entry SYSTEM, granting FULL CONTROL in a Windows DACL?
As far as I've seen it seems to always be there (is it?) but I've not found any explaination for its purpose.

Comment: A number of system services run as SYSTEM, e.g., Windows Update, Windows Search, the Desktop Window Manager Session Manager, and so on.  I believe there are also a number of user-mode threads in the system process.  This ACE ensures that these components can access the file or object in question.

Comment: ... strictly speaking, it is usually redundant, because in most cases there is also an ACE for the Administrators group, which the SYSTEM token includes.  I assume the redundancy is so that you can remove Administrators from the ACL without breaking the operating system's access, or perhaps there are (or used to be) circumstances where an operating system component has SYSTEM but not Administrators.